# What image is loaded with <picture> element?

Tags: html, image, responsive, responsive-images

I'm implementing responsive images on a new website and have a question. Is it correct that the example code below will load `test-400.jpg` on any screen that's 960 pixels or larger? Even if the image width only takes up 40% of the screen width? This is the outcome I'm looking for

I've attempted to work out how I can find in the browser developer tools, what image is being used to work this out for myself but haven't had much success working out how to do that.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 960px)" sizes="100vw" srcset="test-400.jpg">

  <img src="test.jpg"
       srcset="test-310.jpg 310w, test-400.jpg 400w, test-460.jpg 460w, test-620.jpg 620w, test-840.jpg 840w" sizes="(max-width: 959px) 100vw, 50vw"
       alt="test image">
</picture>
```

Comment: Network panel would be one way to check which image resources are actually loaded.

Comment: I did think of that but the page I was testing on had the same image loading at different sizes more than once. I'll set up a new test page with it only loading once and see what happens then - didn't think of that before.

Comment: You haven't added the screenshot for the outcome you're looking for. Your sentence ends: "This is the outcome I'm looking for" and there is no image after that. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in the post but the outcome I was looking for is what is written before that sentence. So would `test-400.jpg` be loaded on a 960 pixel sized screen or larger? Even if the image only took up 40% of the screen size. I'm not sure what type of screen shot would help explain this better?

Comment: Select the `img` in the elements panel and the enter `$0.currentSrc` in the console.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas That's great - I wasn't able to find that anywhere while Googling but it shows what image is currently loaded by the `<img`. Also it answered my question & test-400.jpg is being loaded on screens larger than 960 pixels.

Comment: Maybe @alexanderfarkas should put his comment in the "answer" box, so that you accept it… ;-)

Comment: NicolasHoizey in his absence I have done this.  @alexanderfarkas thanks so much for the help this was so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `img` in the elements panel and the enter `$0.currentSrc` in the console to find out which element is being used.

Importantly you cannot select the `<picture>` or any of the `<source>` elements it must be the `<img` part.  If you receive "undefined" then the chances are you have picked the incorrect part of the element.

If the correct part is selected you will receive an output of a single image location.

[image: screenshot of picture element selected incorrectly vs img selected correctly]